# Kafka to Flink to Hive - Writes failing

Tags: hive, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to Sink data to Hive via Kafka -> Flink -> Hive using following code snippet:

But I am getting following error:

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataStream<GenericRecord> stream = readFromKafka(env);


private static final TypeInformation[] FIELD_TYPES = new TypeInformation[]{
        BasicTypeInfo.INT_TYPE_INFO, BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO
};

 JDBCAppendTableSink sink = JDBCAppendTableSink.builder()
            .setDrivername("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
            .setDBUrl("jdbc:hive2://hiveconnstring")
            .setUsername("myuser")
            .setPassword("mypass")
            .setQuery("INSERT INTO testHiveDriverTable (key,value) VALUES (?,?)")
            .setBatchSize(1000)
            .setParameterTypes(FIELD_TYPES)
            .build();

    DataStream<Row> rows = stream.map((MapFunction<GenericRecord, Row>) st1 -> {
                Row row = new Row(2); // 
                row.setField(0, st1.get("SOME_ID")); 
                row.setField(1, st1.get("SOME_ADDRESS"));
                return row;
            });

    sink.emitDataStream(rows);
    env.execute("Flink101");


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Execution of JDBC statement failed.
at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCOutputFormat.flush(JDBCOutputFormat.java:219)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCSinkFunction.snapshotState(JDBCSinkFunction.java:43)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.trySnapshotFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:118)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.snapshotFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:99)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.snapshotState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:90)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.snapshotState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:356)
... 12 more

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeBatch(HiveStatement.java:381)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCOutputFormat.flush(JDBCOutputFormat.java:216)
... 17 more
```

I checked hive-jdbc driver and it seems that the Method is not supported in hive-jdbc driver.

```
public class HiveStatement implements java.sql.Statement {
...

  @Override  
  public int[] executeBatch() throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException("Method not supported");
  }

..
}
```

Is there any way we can achieve this using JDBC Driver ?

Let me know,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Confluent Platform comes with HDFS Connect, which has Hive Integration

Comment: We have few other requirements where Flink will be the central data processing location for entire company and hence looking for Kafka->Flink->Hive integration

Answer (score 1):

Hive's JDBC implementation is not complete yet. Your problem is tracked by [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-16221).

You could try to patch Flink's `JDBCOutputFormat` to not use batching by replacing `upload.addBatch` with `upload.execute` in `JDBCOutputFormat.java:202` and remove the call to `upload.executeBatch` in `JDBCOutputFormat.java:216`. The down side will be that you issue for every record a dedicated SQL query which might slow down things.